# Splitting names that include "de", "da", etc. into first, middle, last, etc

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to split Brazilian names into parts. However there are names like below where `"de"`, `"da"` (and others) that are not separate parts and they always go with the following word. So normal split doesn't work.

```
test1 = "Francisco da Sousa Rodrigues" #special split
test2 = "Emiliano Rodrigo Carrasco" #normal split
test3 = "Alberto de Francia" #special split
test4 = "Bruno Rezende" #normal split
```

My expected output would be:

```
[Francisco, da Sousa, Rodrigues] #1
[Emiliano, Rodrigo, Carrasco] #2
[Alberto, de Francia] #3
[Bruno, Rezende] #4
```

For the special cases I tried this pattern:

```
PATTERN = re.compile(r"\s(?=[da, de, do, dos, das])")
re.split(PATTERN, test1) (...)
```

but the output is not what I expected:

```
['Francisco', 'da Sousa Rodrigues'] #1
['Alberto', 'de Francia'] #3
```

Any idea how to fix it? Is there a way to just use one pattern for both "normal" and "special" case?

Comment: @pawelty Ok OP. *Why do you want to split the names?*

Comment: I want to count how often each part appears in Firstname and how often in Surname. Then, according to our editorial guidelines I would separate them into first/middle/surname fields. It might not be perfect in 100% cases but we're fine with that.

Comment: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: @pawelty  I don't have a better solution as far as regex goes, but why you don't just split everything then iterate over the resulting list, searching for "de" and joining it with the next item in the list as string ?  Seems conceptually easier, but I am guessing you have a performance reason there, right ? Don't misunderstand, not questioning your methods, quite the opposite - want to learn  what others are doing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Will the names always be written in the "canonical" way, i.e. with every part capitalised except for da, de, do, ...?

In that case, you can use that fact:

```
>>> import re
>>> for t in (test1, test2, test3, test4):
... print(re.findall(r"(?:[a-z]+ )?[A-Z]\w+", t, re.UNICODE))
['Francisco', 'da Sousa', 'Rodrigues']
['Emiliano', 'Rodrigo', 'Carrasco']
['Alberto', 'de Francia']
['Bruno', 'Rezende']
>>>
```

The "right" way to do what you want to do (apart from not doing it at all), would be a negative lookbehind: split when on a space that isn't preceeded by any of da, de, do, ... . Sadly, this is (AFAIK) impossible, because `re` requires lookbehinds to be of equal width. If no names *end* in the syllables, which you really can't assume, you *could* do this:

```
PATTERN = re.compile(r"(?<! da| de| do|dos|das)\s")
```

---

You may or may not occasionally stumble about cases that don't work: If the first letter is an accented character (or the article, hypothetically, contained one), it will match incorrectly. To fix this, you won't get around using an external library; [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex).

Your new findall will look like this then:

```
regex.findall(r"(?:\p{Ll}+ )?\p{Lu}\w+", "Luiz Ângelo de Urzêda")
```

The `\p{Ll}` refers to *any* lowercase letter, and `\p{Lu}` to *any* uppercase letter.

Comment: *'..every part **capitalised** except...'*

Comment: There are many good answers here but I will use this one. Just confirmed with the team that all the "special" words will be written in lower case. Thanks

Comment: @L3viathan I have problem with this approach when word starts with some weird letter like test5 = "Luiz Ângelo de Urzêda" . It totally skips the second word.

Comment: @pawelty I foresaw the problem and edited my answer an hour ago; you're gonna need the `regex` module.

Comment: This is fine if you only care about typical Brazilian names.  It works less well if you have a Brazilian citizen named "Kitty St John O'Connor." (She was actually Irish, and the mother of [Norman St. John-Stevas](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2012/mar/05/lord-st-john-of-fawsley).)

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex in `findall` with an optional group:

```
(?:(?:da|de|do|dos|das)\s+)?\S+
```

Here we make `(?:da|de|do|dos|das)` and 1+ whitespace following this optional.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7XEHqG/3)

[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/awD5E9)

**Code Example:**

```
test1 = "Francisco da Sousa Rodrigues" #special split
test2 = "Emiliano Rodrigo Carrasco" #normal split
test3 = "Alberto de Francia" #special split
test4 = "Bruno Rezende" #normal split

PATTERN = re.compile(r'(?:(?:da|de|do|dos|das)\s+)?\S+')

>>> print re.findall(PATTERN, test1)
['Francisco', 'da Sousa', 'Rodrigues']

>>> print re.findall(PATTERN, test2)
['Emiliano', 'Rodrigo', 'Carrasco']

>>> print re.findall(PATTERN, test3)
['Alberto', 'de Francia']

>>> print re.findall(PATTERN, test4)
['Bruno', 'Rezende']
```

Comment: this is incorrect behaviour for test1 and test2. Last word is not separated.

Comment: Sorry for the goof up. I have updated the answer to get the correct output.

Answer (score 2):

With `regex.split()` function from python's [**`regex`**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) library which  offers additional functionality:

installation:

```
pip install regex
```

usage:

```
import regex as re

test_names = ["Francisco da Sousa Rodrigues", "Emiliano Rodrigo Carrasco",
              "Alberto de Francia", "Bruno Rezende"]

for n in test_names:
    print(re.split(r'(?<!das?|de|dos?)\s+', n))
```

The output:

```
['Francisco', 'da Sousa', 'Rodrigues']
['Emiliano', 'Rodrigo', 'Carrasco']
['Alberto', 'de Francia']
['Bruno', 'Rezende']
```

---

- `(?<!das?|de|dos?)\s+` - lookbehind negative assertion `(?<!...)` ensures that whitespace(s) `\s+` is not preceded with one of the special cases `da|das|de|do|dos`

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/

Comment: I get this error: error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern

Comment: @pawelty, I apologize, this is the solution with extended `regex` library which offers  offers additional functionality. See my update

Answer (score 1):

One can achieve this stepwise after replacing da with da_ and de with de_:

```
lst = ["Francisco da Sousa Rodrigues" , 
    "Emiliano Rodrigo Carrasco" , 
    "Alberto de Francia" , 
    "Bruno Rezende" ] 

# replace da with da_ and de with de_
lst = list(map(lambda x: x.replace(" da ", " da_"), lst) ) 
lst = list(map(lambda x: x.replace(" de ", " de_"), lst) ) 
# now split names and then convert back _ to space: 
lst = [ [k.replace("_", " ")
        for k in l.split()]
      for l in lst ]
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[['Francisco', 'da Sousa', 'Rodrigues'], 
 ['Emiliano', 'Rodrigo', 'Carrasco'], 
 ['Alberto', 'de Francia'], 
 ['Bruno', 'Rezende']]
```

Edit: in response to the comment, if "Fernanda Rezende" type names are there then one can replace `" da "` with `" da_"` (code above changed to this from earlier `"da "` to `"da_"`)

One can also define a simple function for making changes in all strings of a list, and then use it:

```
def strlist_replace(slist, oristr, newstr):
    return [ s.replace(oristr, newstr)
             for s in slist ]

lst = strlist_replace(lst, " da ", " da_")
lst = strlist_replace(lst, " de ", " de_")
```

Comment: Fails for `"Fernanda Rezende"`

Comment: I think this could be improved with check for `.startswith("da")`

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you split the string at your special pattern. This will indeed split the string in two parts.

You could try splitting the second part further, using " " as a delimiter once more. Note that this doesn't work in case there are multiple instances of special delimiters.

Another approach would be to keep splitting using " " as delimiter, and join each special delimiter with the following name. For example:

```
[Francisco, da, Sousa, Rodrigues] # becomes...
[Francisco, da Sousa, Rodrigues]
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try something like this ?

```
b_o_g=['da', 'de', 'do', 'dos', 'das']
test1 = "Francisco da Sousa Rodrigues"
test3= "Alberto de Francia"




def _custom_split (bag_of_words,string_t):
    s_o_s = string_t.split()
    for _,__ in enumerate(s_o_s):
        if __ in bag_of_words:
            try:
                s_o_s[_]="{} {}".format(s_o_s[_],s_o_s[_+1])
                del s_o_s [ _ + 1]

            except IndexError:
                pass
    return s_o_s

print(_custom_split(b_o_g,test1))
print(_custom_split(b_o_g,test3))
```

output:

```
['Francisco', 'da Sousa', 'Rodrigues']
['Alberto', 'de Francia']
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best or elegant way but this will work. I also added the test5 just to be sure.

```
special_chars = ['da', 'de', 'do', 'dos', 'das']

test1 = "Francisco da Sousa Rodrigues" #special split
test2 = "Emiliano Rodrigo Carrasco" #normal split
test3 = "Alberto de Francia" #special split
test4 = "Bruno Rezende" #normal split
test5 = 'Francisco da Sousa de Rodrigues'

def cut(test):
    t1 = test.split()
    for i in range(len(t1)):
        if t1[i] in special_chars:
            t1[i+1] = t1[i] + ' ' + t1[i+1]
    for i in t1:
        if i in special_chars:
            t1.remove(i)
    print(t1)

cut(test1)
cut(test2)
cut(test3)
cut(test4)
cut(test5)
```

The results are:

```
['Francisco', 'da Sousa', 'Rodrigues']
['Emiliano', 'Rodrigo', 'Carrasco']
['Alberto', 'de Francia']
['Bruno', 'Rezende']
['Francisco', 'da Sousa', 'de Rodrigues']
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be pointed out that we are talking about titles here, not names.

These pretty much all translate to something like "from" or "of" and the part after typically refers to a place and they originated as titles for nobility.

You are trying to fit a non-name into a name context, which makes everything difficult.

It's weird to try to just remove all this like it doesn't exist.  Like if you take a name such as "Steve From New York" and to just try to drop the from and make New York the "last name".

These were never intended to be last names or to act like what to most people would be a last name.  Things just kinda drifted in that direction over time trying to make round pegs fit into square holes.

You might add a title field to your signup page or something and direct it to be used for people with titles as a more elegant solution.

Answer (score -2):

Your regular expression should be changed into

PATTERN = re.compile(r"\s(?=[da, de, do, dos, das])(\S+\s*\s\s*\S+)")

```
import re

test1 = "Francisco da Sousa Rodrigues" #special split
test3 = "Alberto de Francia" #special split

PATTERN = re.compile(r"\s(?=[da, de, do, dos, das])(\S+\s*\s\s*\S+)")
print re.split(PATTERN, test1)
print re.split(PATTERN, test3)
```

This works for me giving the following outputs,

['Francisco', 'da Sousa', ' Rodrigues']
['Alberto', 'de Francia', '']

Comment: @ktsenuri The `[da, de, do, dos, das]` does not do what you're expecting it to do. It's equivalent to `[adeos, ]`, that is, match any of those characters including a comma or space.

Comment: @cpburnz Thanks for figuring out , hence it should be changed to PATTERN = re.compile(r"\s(?=[da | de| do| dos| das])(\S+\s*\s\s*\S+)")

Comment: @ktsenuri No, `[...]` is only used to match sets of characters, not words. You'd want `(?=da |de |do |dos |das )`.